# Bad/Missing Values Output - Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a .csv file to be accessed by Pandas library and was asked to find null/missing values. I tried doing it but I could not find any. As this is a graded assignment, I wanted to try it by myself first and I did (attaching code below) but I am just not able to do it and am hence seeking help.

[Here is the task.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc5Vl.png)

```
# Find missing values - PB Dataset
missing_values = pb.isnull().sum().sum()
print('Number of missing values in PB Dataset:', missing_values)

# Find bad values - PB Dataset
bad_values = pb.isin(['', '?', 'NA', 'N/A', 'NaN']).sum().sum()
print('Number of bad values in PB Dataset:', bad_values)

print()

# Find missing values - TR Dataset
missing_values = tr.isnull().sum().sum()
print('Number of missing values in TR Dataset:', missing_values)

# Find bad values - TR Dataset
bad_values = tr.isin(['', '?', 'NA', 'N/A', 'NaN']).sum().sum()
print('Number of bad values in TR Dataset:', bad_values)
```

The respective .csv files are here --> [File 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UQvMDoCY2dAstJL0uM6Yh_ILKL1wUkw2/view?usp=share_link) and [File 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15sXif1Jzr-ugZiiWNLU_d_gYzXYMnAdq/view?usp=share_link).

Please help. Thanks a lot!

```
import pandas as pd

# read the Purchase Behaviour CSV file using pandas
pb = pd.read_csv('pb.csv')

print("\033[1;37;40m{:^80}\033[0m".format("Data at a glance -- Purchase Behaviour Dataset"))
print()
print(pb.head()) # Data at glance
print()
print()

# count the total rows and columns in the data
num_rows = len(pb.index)
num_cols = len(pb.columns)

# print the total rows and columns
print(f"Total Rows in Purchase Behaviour Dataset: {num_rows}")
print(f"Total Columns in Purchase Behaviour Dataset: {num_cols}")
print("\033[1;33;40m{}\033[0m".format("I will be referring to Purchase Behaviour Dataset as 'PB Dataset'"))
#Doing the same with Transactions Dataset
print()
print()

print("\033[1;37;40m{:^80}\033[0m".format("Data at a glance -- Transactions Dataset"))
print()
tr = pd.read_csv('tr.csv')

print(tr.head()) #  Data at glance
print()
print()


# count the total rows and columns in the data
num_rows = len(tr.index)
num_cols = len(tr.columns)

# print the total rows and columns
print(f"Total Rows in Transactions Dataset: {num_rows}")
print(f"Total Columns in Transactions Dataset: {num_cols}")
print("\033[1;33;40m{}\033[0m".format("I will be referring to Transactions Dataset as 'TR Dataset'"))

print()
print()
print("\033[1;37;40m{:^80}\033[0m".format("Data Preparation -- Finding Missing Values"))
print()

# Find missing values - PB Dataset
missing_values = pb.isnull().sum().sum()
print('Number of missing values in PB Dataset:', missing_values)

# Find bad values - PB Dataset
bad_values = pb.isin(['', '?', 'NA', 'N/A', 'NaN']).sum().sum()
print('Number of bad values in PB Dataset:', bad_values)

print()

# Find missing values - TR Dataset
missing_values = tr.isnull().sum().sum()
print('Number of missing values in TR Dataset:', missing_values)

# Find bad values - TR Dataset
bad_values = tr.isin(['', '?', 'NA', 'N/A', 'NaN']).sum().sum()
print('Number of bad values in TR Dataset:', bad_values)
```

Comment: The assignment does not ask you to COUNT the missing values.  It asks you to HANDLE them, presumably by replacing them.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hey @TimRoberts so I wanted to count them as an additional step, my bad that I didn't mention, but the output of count is coming in as 0. Which is what confuses me.

Comment: Have you examined the data?  Are you quite sure what the signal for missing data is in these datasets?

Comment: Maybe the goal is to find the gaps in the index column?